# My 768px media query isn't working, what could be causing this?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have set up a media query for iPad/Tablets at 768px but when I resize my browser either using the window or the Dev Tools device toolbar. It doesn't work? I have tested by changing the font size to 400px and nothing changes.

CSS

```
@media only screen and(min-width: 768px){
    body{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    button{ 
        width: 60% !important;
    }
    input{
        width: calc(60% - 1em) !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: add a space inside `and (min-width: 768px)` and get some css linter or syntax checker, please

Comment: @mac might be some other media queries overriding your media query. remove other media queries and check

Comment: be sure your media queries are placed at the bottom of your css sheet.

Comment: @AkhilAravind it was the only media query at the time of writiing

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez they are at the bottom

Comment: @noomorph it is written in scss

Comment: did you tried toggling `min-width` and `max-width`

Comment: I just test it and work well https://jsfiddle.net/7r14bazs/2/ (be aware of the space mentionned by @noomorph) -> If screen is upper that `768px` the background is red.

Comment: @johannchopin, moreover, if I turn on SCSS there, the original example works as well: https://jsfiddle.net/mgdb6xco/

So, the problem is outside of this question.